# Magento : get attribute value php

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

i have tow attributes described in the image bellow :

[image]

i wanna know how to get value of it

```
________
_________
_________
```

Thanks !

Comment: Answer given by Mohit Kumar Arora should work

Comment: @DushyantJoshi for allow custom price there is just Yes/No but i wanna add useconfig option too like Apply Map select how can i do that ?

Comment: Can you put it as different question so that others can answer with what you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531263/magento-attribute-select-options this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load the product model:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(<product_id>);
```

then use:

```
$allowCustomPrice = $product->getAttributeText('allow_custom_price');
```

and

```
$minPrice = $product->getMinPrice();
```

Note:   I am asuming, that you will replace  with original product id, and attribute codes are "allow_custom_price" and "min_price" respectively.