# Magento : attribute select options

Tags: magento

for allow custom price there is just Yes/No but i wanna add "use config" option too like Apply Map select how can i do that ?

this is the attribute :

```
$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'allow_customprice', array(

        'group'                       => 'Prices',
        'input'                       => 'select',
        'label'                       => 'Allow Custom Price',
        'source'                      => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'backend'                     => '',
        'visible'                     => 1,
        'required'                    => 0,
        'user_defined'                => 1,
        'searchable'                  => 1,
        'filterable'                  => 0,
        'default'                     => 1,
        'comparable'                  => 1,
        'visible_on_front'            => 1,
        'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'    => 0,
        'global'                      => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,

));
```

thats the system.xml :

```
                    <fields>
                        <enablecp translate="label">
                            <label>Enable Custom Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <comment>Option for all products.</comment>
                            <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </enablecp>
                         <!-- END FIELD -->

                        <minprice translate="label">
                            <label>Min Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <validate>validate-number</validate>
                            <comment>Min price for all products.</comment>
                            <sort_order>60</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </minprice>
                        <!-- END FIELD -->

                    </fields>
```

thats it thanks for advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your attribute configuration you set the source model to `eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean`. This class contains the following method which fills the option data:

```
 public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('eav')->__('Yes'),
                    'value' => self::VALUE_YES
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('eav')->__('No'),
                    'value' => self::VALUE_NO
                ),
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
```

When you want to modify it create your own source class and extend it from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract`.

**EDIT:**

You can take `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Source_Boolean` as your source. It contains the options:

- Yes
- No
- Use Config

So the source should be set to: `catalog/product_attribute_source_boolean`

Comment: do u see Apply map in Product Prices it uses yes-no-use config whats that class ?